# CDI Bean with executing JPA queries

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

Short question, shall a bean/instance in javaEE (wildfly, cdi) be @RequestScoped if its executing jpa queries inside (only selects) or shall I always use @stateless for jpa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the point of the question.

If you have a business layer and the possibility to use EJB I would go for a `@Stateless` holding business logic and JPA interaction, and exposing a specific business interface to client.

In any case, if you are just doing a select and nothing else, maybe for filling your datatable on front end, I suggest to annotate your business method like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public List<MyEntity> findByWhateverCriteria(String param) {
  // business logic
}
```

why ? Because you can save application server resources.

On the other side, a @RequestScoped is appropriate if, for the same reason above, you only need to display data on front end and forget about it.